# Hibernate Many-To-Many Relationship with Composite Key Circular JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

I have a many-to-many entity relationship with some extra attributes and a composite key in Spring Boot using JPA/Hibernate, but a JSON serialization of entity/entities results in a circular JSON, which throws an exception.

The basic table structure is as follows (cols = entity/table, rows = attributes):

| user | user_role | role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | user_id | id |
| f_name | role_id | name |
| l_name | assigned_at | alias |

In Spring Boot this is represented with the following relationship:

```
@Embeddable
class UserRoleKey implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "user_id")
  private long userId;

  @Column(name = "role_id")
  private long roleId;

  public UserRoleKey() {}

  // hash, equals omitted for brevity
  // getter/setter for userId, roleId omitted for brevity

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_role")
class UserRole {

  @EmbeddedId
  private UserRoleKey id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @MapsId("userId")
  private User user;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @MapsId("roleId")
  private Role role;

  @Temporal
  @Column(name = "assigned_at")
  private Date assignedAt;

  public UserRole() {}

  // hash, equals omitted for brevity
  // getter/setter for user, role, assignedAt omitted for brevity

}
```

Where the two individual entities are represented as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  private String fName;
  private String lName;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
  private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

  // hash, equals omitted for brevity
  // getter/setter for fName, lName, userRoles omitted for brevity

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
class Role {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  private String name;
  private String alias;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role")
  private Set<UserRole> roleUsers = new HashSet<>();

  // hash, equals omitted for brevity
  // getter/setter for name, alias, roleUsers omitted for brevity

}
```

Whenever the list of `User`s is fetched via the API via the repository's `findAll` method, the returned `User` JSON recurses on `User` indefinitely, causing an exception. The resulting JSON of an `User` entity looks like this:

```
User:
{
  "id": 0,
  "fName": "John",
  "lName": "Doe",
  "userRoles" = [
    {
      "user": {
        // Infinite recursion!
        "id": 0,
        "fName": "John",
        "lName": "Doe",
        "userRoles" = [
          ....
        ]
      },
      "role": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Administrator",
        "alias": "admin"
      },
      "assignedAt": "dummy_timestamp"
    }, ...
  ]
}
```

The same issue appears if the relationship is used in the oposite direction, i.e. via `Role`.

Is there something I'm missing here? I went through loads of different resources on Hibernate/JPA/Spring, but I can't seem to spot what's wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @JsonIgnore on one relationship to break the cycle.

Comment: The `@JsonIgnore` would need to be placed in `UserRole` for either the `user` or the `role` attributes, respectively, I assume?

Comment: If depends how your JSON must look like

Comment: That fixes the problem, but shouldn't there also be a way to make this work such that it's bi-directional? This way you can only use the mapping in getting all `Role`s a `User` belongs to, but not the other way around.

Comment: Bidirectional relationships are cycles. And JSON is hierarchical. So this would produce an infinites JSON file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get userRoles where user object have no userRoles attached you can make this relation unidirectional by removing `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "role")`  from Role class.

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the problem, it appears to make no difference whether `Role` maps back to `User` as well or not..